Transform a list of rules into a list of function definitions
I have a list of rules obtained by solving a system of equations, e.g.
{f[x] -> a + 3 h[x], g[x] -> 2 a + c + 6 h[x]}.
I wish to convert this list of rules into a list of function definitions, i.e.
f[x_]:=a + 3 h[x];
g[x_]:=2 a + c + 6 h[x];
I tried several solutions, but none of them work perfectly. My best solution is this one:
E1 = f[x] - 3 h[x] - a;
E2 = g[x] - 2 f[x] - c;
eqn = {E1, E2};
var = {f, g};
sol = Solve[Table[eqn[[p]] == 0,{p,1,Length[eqn]}], Table[Through[var[x]][[p]],{p,1,Length[var]}]][[1]];
For[i=1, i<=Length[var], i++, var[[i]][x_] := Evaluate[Values[sol][[i]]];]

And it works :
f[x] returns a+3 h[x] and f'[x] returns 3 h'[x].
But when I turn the last line of the above code into a function :
Mydef[var_,sol_]:=For[i=1, i<=Length[var], i++, var[[i]][x_]:= Evaluate[Values[sol][[i]]];];

it doesn't work anymore. I execute Mydef[var,sol] instead of the last line of the above code and then f[x] returns a+3 h[x] BUT f'[x] returns 0.
I don't understand this problem and I'm sure there are much better ways of doing what I want to do. Thanks for any help you can give.
Stan.

rules = {f[x] -> a + 3 h[x], g[x] -> 2 a + c + 6 h[x]}
MapThread[(#1 = Function[{x}, #2]) &, {Head /@ First /@ rules,  Last /@ rules}]
Check:
f[z] (*a + 3 h[z]*)
g[q]  (*2 a + c + 6 h[q]*)

@Ulrich beat me to it as I was writing up my answer....  Vote his up!

That seems to work very well with my big systems. Thank you !

To achieve this, we need to manipulate the "DownValues" of the function names. We use "Scan" to operate on all elements of the rule list.  As "DownValues" has the attribute "HoldAll" we need "Evaluate" to dig out the information from the argument of Scan":
ClearAll["Global`*"]
rules = {f[x] -> a + 3 h[x], g[x] -> 2 a + c + 6 h[x]};

Scan[(DownValues[Evaluate[#[[1, 0]]]] = {Evaluate[#[[1, 0]]][x_] -> Evaluate[#[[2]]]}) &, rules]

We may look at the "DownValues" of f and g:
DownValues[f]

{HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> a + 3 h[x]}

DownValues[g]

{HoldPattern[g[x_]] :> 2 a + c + 6 h[x]}

Or we may test f ang by giving an argument:
 f[2]

 a + 3 h[2]
 
 g[3]
 
 2 a + c + 6 h[3]


If the left-hand sides of each rule depend on the same variable, @Craig Carter's solution is sufficient, but if not, we can generalize this process using ReplaceAll as follows:
AssignFunction[r_Rule | r : {__Rule}] := r /. Rule[h_[a_], b_] :> 
Set[h, Function @@ {a, b}]

Testing AssignFunction with the simple case:
rules1 = {f[x] -> a + 3 h[x], g[x] -> 2 a + c + 6 h[x]};

AssignFunction[rules1]

f[x] (*a + 3 h[x]*)

g[x] (*2 a + c + 6 h[x]*)

Testing AssignFunction with a pair of rules with different independent variables on their left-hand sides:
rules2 = {f[x] -> a + 3 h[x], g[z] -> 2 a + c + 6 h[z]};

AssignFunction[rules2]

f[x] (*a + 3 h[x]*)

g[z] (*2 a + c + 6 h[z]*)

If you apply @Craig Carter's idea to rules2, the problem is that you don't capture the fact that the right-hand side of the second rule in rules2 depends on z and not x. However, as @G. Shults rightly points out, a slight modification to @Craig Carter's solution solves this problem:
MapThread[(#1 = Function[{#2}, #3]) &, {Head /@ First /@ rules,    
First /@ First /@ rules, Last /@ rules}]

The definition to include the case of several variables:
AssignFunction[r_Rule | r : {__Rule}] := r /. Rule[h_[a__], b_] :>  
Set[h, Function @@ {{a}, b}]

Testing AssignFunction:
AssignFunction[H[x, y, z] -> x  y  Cos[z]]

H[x, y, z] (*x y Cos[z]*)


A simpler modification @Craig Carter's solution would be to just change his MapThread expression to MapThread[(#1 = Function[{#2}, #3]) &, {Head /@ First /@ rules,    First /@ First /@ rules, Last /@ rules}]

Thanks for pointing this out, @G.Shults! :-)

Another variant that works with several variables:
Clear[define] ;
define[rules_] := Block[
  {heads, tails, names},
  {heads, tails} = Transpose[List@@@rules] ;
  names =Map[Head, heads] ;
  heads = MapAt[Pattern[#, Blank[]] &, heads,{All, -1}] ;
  MapThread[SetDelayed, {heads,tails}] ;
  names
]

(* initial call *)

ClearAll@@{f, g, fxyz} ;
rules = {f[x] -> a + 3 h[x], g[x] -> 2 a + c + 6 h[x], fxyz[x,y,z] -> x y z} ;
names = define[rules] ;

f[x]
g[x]
fxyz[x, y, z]

(* need to clean symbols first on subsequent calls *)

ClearAll@@names ;
rules = {f[x] -> a + 3 h[x] + 100, g[x] -> 2 a + c + 6 h[x] * 1, fxyz[x,y,z] -> (x y z)^2} ;
names = define[rules] ;

f[x]
g[x]
fxyz[x, y, z]


Try
E1 = f[x] - 3 h[x] - a;
E2 = g[x] - 2 f[x] - c;
eqn = Map[# == 0 &, {E1, E2}];
sol = Values@Solve[eqn, {f[x], g[x]}]  [[1]]

define functions F,G
{F, G} = Map [ Function[x, # ] &, sol ];

check
{F[x],G[x]} (* {a + 3 h[x], 2 a + c + 6 h[x]} *)


Thank you for this solution. But the functions must have the names initially defined (f and g instead of F and G in your solution). And in my real problem there are 12 equations in the list, with 12 unknown functions, not 2 as in the example above...
